# Laravel API Route controller function parameter

Tags: laravel

Using the following route declaration, I am trying to pass a parameter to the controller method however I am unsure of how to do this. I don't want a route parameter but instead a hard coded parameter so that I can use the same function for both updating the current user and other users using a parameter to distinguish between the two operations.

`Route::patch('/v1/user', [UserController::class, 'update']);`

I need to pass a boolean value to the update method from this Route statement, any ideas?

Comment: how are you accessing your API? meaning what is your frontend language? you can attach variables with your requests which you can read in your Laravel Controller.

Comment: Yes I could do that however I would prefer to have separate routes. /api/v1/user to update the current user and /api/v1/user/{id} to update a specific user ID, but I want to use the same controller method to achieve this, with a variable to inform the controller method which route is calling the method.

Comment: Then you want an Optional Query Parameter: `Route::patch('/v1/user/{id?}', ...);` `id` can be included or excluded, and you can hook into that in the Controller method and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis, exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

There are two simple ways to do this

1. A general method to update the user

```
public function updateUser($user){...}
```

Then you can just call this function from the other controllers. This way, your code becomes flexible and easier to test/mock

2. Make $id as nullable

```
public function update($id = null)
{
    if($id) {
        $user = User::find($id);
    } else {
        $user = auth()->user();
    }
    // Update user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not you mean this?

`Route::patch('/v1/user/{id}', [UserController::class, 'update']);`